# Pandas: If NaN show the NaN row as well as the row above

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I would like Python Pandas to display not only the row with NaN values but also the row above the respective row with NaN values. I need this because if there is a NaN value in a row I need to delete not only the one with NaN values but also the prior row.

Thanks

Comment: An example data frame, the desired output, your attempt and the result would help the people here help you.

Answer (score 0):

Take index of all the rows with NaN values in a list. Then create a new index list by subtracting 1 from it. Then delete those indexes.

```
nan_indexes = df[df.row.isnull()].index.tolist()
row_above_nan = [x-1 for x in nan_indexes]
final_list = nan_indexes + row_above_nan

df = df[~df.index.isin(final_list)]
```